# Adminhtml Collection - Reset pagination, respecting grid filters

Tags: collection, reset-filter

I need to get the full collection, **with adminhtml grid filters applied**, but without the grid pagination

I've tried several things, for instance...

```
$this->getCollection()->clear()->setPageSize(false)->load();
```

But I am getting always the paginated collection

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got this working, with following code

```
$this->getCollection()->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
$this->getCollection()->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
$this->getCollection()->clear()->setPageSize(false)->load();
```

Credits for [Jürgen Thelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693207/j%C3%BCrgen-thelen)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041177/magento-get-all-products-from-a-product-collection-ignoring-the-set-limits